# WARN Message when starting Android Studio 2.2 on Linux

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, terminal

I get these 3 messages in the terminal every time I start up android studio, and was wondering what should be done to fix them?

I'm having a bunch of issues with trying to get the android studio emulator to show my app in the emulator, do these have anything to do with my problem?
(I'm new to both Ubuntu and android studio.)

> [  37020]   WARN - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Errors during XML parse:
>   [  37020]   WARN - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Additionally, the fallback loader failed to parse the XML.
>   [  59591]   WARN - roid.tools.ndk.GradleWorkspace - NDK support for project 'My Application' is disabled because the project doesn't contain any valid native configurations.

Comment: Okay I looked around for a solution to fix a different error, and it looks like that fixed my problem with starting up the emulator.

But should these errors cause any problems with anything later on?

Comment: So what did you do that fixed it?